# Python not finding file on local desktop

Tags: python

I have a simple python script that determines whether a file called `test.csv` is on my desktop or not. I have the file on my desktop, but the script always says it doesn't exit.

I've done some research on it and I've tried using raw strings for the file path and also double quotes instead of single, but none of them worked.

My script is below, it always prints `NOT found`, even if the file exists. OS is Windows 7.
Would python need some kind of permission to read files from my computer?  Thanks in advance.

```
if(os.path.exists('C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\test.csv')):
    print "Found"
else:
    print "NOT Found"
```

Comment: Try making sure every path component exists and double check names. I.e. see `os.path.exists('C:\\Users')` then add next path component etc.

Comment: Does the actual file exist on your desktop, or is it only a shortcut (`.lnk` file)?

Comment: Pajton, good suggestion. That works all the way until I added the test.csv, then it said that doesn't exist. So C:\\Users\user\\Desktop existed, but not C:\\Users\user\\Desktop\\test.csv.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi, the file does exists and isn't a shortcut.

Comment: Could you verify you didn't make a mistake in desktop path? Copy the path, replace double `\` with single and paste it into explorer "address" bar.

Comment: The problem was due to the file name was actually test.csv.xslx (the xslx was hidden.) If you post your comment I will accept it as the answer since yours led me to the answer John.

Comment: Protip: Windows explorer > Organize > Folder and search options. View tab, enable 'Show hidden files, folders, and drives'  and uncheck 'Hide extensions for known file types'. Click Apply to folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use os.path.expanduser to get the correct path to the desktop

```
if(os.path.exists(os.path.expanduser('~/Desktop/test.csv')):
    print "Found"
else:
    print "NOT Found"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import os


if(os.path.exists('C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\test.csv')) == True:
    print("Found")
else:
    print("NOT Found")
```

you can also do it like this, `'C:/Users/user/Desktop/test.csv'` which is a little neater

**edited: the destination was incorrect**

Comment: `os.path.exists` returns a boolean, so the comparison to True is unnecessary.  That's what people are downvoting you.

Comment: Actually I'd say they are downvoting for the corrected text being exactly equivalent to the one posed in the problem. IMO the fact that the comparison with True is unnecessary wouldn't deserve a downvote,since explicit is better than implicit, right?

Comment: the questioner would like the file to be found on his desktop. The questioner did not specify if that should or should not come in a boolean format, in fact, they encouraged it by using it in their own code.

Comment: @user2890668, what Cody Piersall has pointed out that the comparison with True is unnecessary, since the answer of os.path.exists (a boolean) compared to a True will just give exactly the same boolean as os.path.exists gives. If you remove "== True" you will get exactly the same behavior. 

My point was more: your code does not differentiate in anything from the original one (which didn't work) so I think that's the reason for the downvote. Anyway, it is not important...